# Swiping horizontally through pages, with a vertical page transition on click of button

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, swipe, swiper.js

**UPDATE** (Original question is below this section)

I have the Swiper plugin integrated like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
        <!--This contains all scripts including the Swiper plugin-->

        <link href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <script src="js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>   
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.css">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/css/swiper.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.2/js/swiper.jquery.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>

<div class="swiper-container">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="pagea">
        <div data-role="page" id="pagea">
           <!--Page A content in here-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="pageb">
        <div data-role="page" id="pageb">
           <!--Page B content in here-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="pagec">
        <div data-role="page" id="pagec">
           <!--Page C content in here-->
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="paged">
        <div data-role="page" id="paged">
           <!--Page D content in here-->
           <!--Page D contains a button to make Page E slide down into view-->
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>
<!--Horizontal Swiping between the 4 main pages ends here-->

<!--The Page to slide down & up vertically here-->

<div class="swiper-container-vertical">
<div class="swiper-wrapper">

    <div class="swiper-slide" data-hash="pagee">
        <div data-role="page" id="pagee">
           <!--Page E content in here-->
           <!--Page E contains a button to make it slide up out of view again-->
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
</div>


         <script>
          <!-- Initialize Swiper -->
          $( window ).on( "load", function() { 
          window.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
              hashnav: true,
              hashnavWatchState: true,
              direction: 'horizontal',
          });

          <!-- Initialize Vertical Swiper -->
          $( window ).on( "load", function() { 
          window.swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container-vertical', {
              hashnav: true,
              hashnavWatchState: true,
              direction: 'vertical',
          });
          </script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Pages A, B, C and D are swiping horizontally correctly. However, in the above example I've created another instance of the Swiper for vertical swiping, I was hoping to be able to trigger Page E sliding in vertically over Page A on click of a button. But I can't seem to get it to work.

This code is a normal jquery vertical/slide down transition:
`$.mobile.changePage("#pagee", { transition: "slidedown", reverse: false }, true, true);` and it was working perfectly before I integrated the Swiper plugin, but now it does nothing. And the Swiper plugin seems to turn any page that has the attribute `data-role="page"` into a black/blank page.

The above jquery mobile vertical transition was what I was looking for, but jquery mobile's horizontal swiping action didn't have the great responsiveness that Swiper does.

Is there any way to somehow merge the two, so that pages A, B, C and D swipe horizontally using Swiper, and Page E can be triggered to slide down and up vertically over Page A? (Perhaps Page A would need to have both classes `swiper-container` and `swiper-container-vertical` in order to handle both the horizontal swipe to Page B, and the vertical drop down of Page E? But I don't know how to do this.)

Or, is there a method in the Swiper plugin that can handle this vertical transition over the horizontal swiping pages?

**Original Question:**

I'm developing a HTML Cordova app and I'm using the Swiper plugin: http://idangero.us/swiper to swipe horizontally between the 4 main pages of my app (this is working perfectly and I love the responsiveness of the plugin).

However I also want to trigger a 5th page to slide in vertically from the top of the viewport on click of a button (located on one of the main pages), this 5th page then slides up vertically the same way it came in on click of another button. (Basically acting like a drop-down menu/page)

I've been trying to achieve this by mixing the Swiper plugin with jquery's mobile page transitions, but the two don't seem to be compatible, as whenever I add the `data-role=page` value to the page in question, it appears as a blank/black space when the Swiper plugin initiates.

Is it possible to do such a thing? And if not, does anyone know of any plugin or method that can do this?

Comment: there should be no compatibility issues, beside the plausibility to use two tools to achieve the same goal. please post some code.

Comment: Hi @deblocker thanks for your reply! I've updated the question with code and a more detailed explanation of the problem, I'd really appreciate if you could take a look at it and let me know what you think. Thank you in advance!

Comment: you have to include a reference to jQuery Mobile in the head section.

Comment: Hi @deblocker thanks again, I had the jQuery Mobile references in the head section of my project but I didn't include them in my question, sorry. I've added the scripts from my project into the head section of the question now, could you take another look?